# Android activity icon smaller than Main Activity icon?

Tags: android

In recents view the activity icon either set directly in Manifest or through 
`setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(title, icon));` is smaller than the original icon itself (when starting app for example). How can this be? Im even using the same icon i get it with like 10% white border around.

Comment: show image of error.

Comment: No error. The icon is smaller than original.